# Is it possible to reimplement "apply" in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, interpreter, apply

If I encounter a primitive procedure, do I always use the underlying scheme apply?

Assuming I do so, how would I re-implement apply for the scheme interpreter to interpret itself?

```
(define apply-1 

  (lambda (proc args)

    (cond ((primitive? proc)
           (apply proc args)) <-- How would I reimplement this
           ((eq? (car proc) 'closure)
            (eval (cadr (cadr proc)) 
                  (bind (car (cdr proc)) args (caddr proc))))  
           (else error))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Primitive-apply is the glue between how a primitive in your interpreter is implemented with the underlying implementation. Using hosts `apply` to apply primitives that are indeed procedures in the host system is a trick. You cannot make a host `apply` but you can make a `interpreter` primitive-apply differently that does less or supports other ways to package primitives. Eg.

```
;; define representations for primitives
(define prim-cons (list 'cons)) ; system unique
(define prim-car  (list 'car))
...

;; define primitive? 
(define (primitive? proc)
  (or (eq? proc prim-cons)
      (eq? proc prim-car)
      ...))

;; define primitive apply
(define (primitive-apply proc args)
  (cond ((eq? proc prim-cons) args)
        ((eq? proc prim-car) (caar args))
        ...))

;; boot environment
(define primitive-environment
  (list (cons #t    prim-true)
        (cons #f    prim-false)
        (cons '()   prim-null)
        (cons 'cons prim-cons)
        (cond 'car  prim-car)
        ...))
```

The fact is using `apply` is just a simplification since the actual primitive procedure is the resolved object. It doesn't always have to be like that. Imagine we try to optimize it a little:

```
;; define representations for primitives
(define prim-cons (list 'cons)) ; system unique
(define prim-car  (list 'car))

;; make a list of primitives and their implementation
(define primitives
  (list (cons prim-cons values)
        (cons prim-car  caar)))

;; define primitive? 
(define (primitive? proc)
  (assq proc primitives))

;; make apply-primitive
(define (apply-primitive proc args)
  ((cdr (primitive? proc)) args))
```

Still lot of boilerplate.. Why not move the whole primitive-list into the environment.

```
;; make tags
(define *primitive* (list 'primitive))
(define *constant* (list 'constant))

;; make a list of primitives and their implementation
(define boot-env
  (list (list* 'cons *primitive* values)
        (list* 'cons *primitive* caar)
        ...
        (list* #f *constant* #f)
        (list* #t *constant* #t)))

;; verify type
(define (is-type? x type)
  (and (pair? proc)
       (eq? (car proc) type)))

;; define primitive? 
(define (primitive? proc)
  (is-type proc *primitive*))

(define (constant? x)
  (is-type x *constant*))

;; make apply-primitive
(define (apply-primitive proc args)
  ((cdr proc) args))
```

Now. For compound procedures we just have similar tag. `eval` itself become very small since you can even have `*special-form*` in your environment that does something similar making your `eval` just a case analysis between the types of values you eval and not special cases.

One of my thought about `apply` was that I wanted my `apply` to be the one called when you call the procedure `apply` from the interpreter. You can make use of `apply`, but `apply` actually needs to be handled by `apply` as well. You'll meet the same weird thing when you try to apply `eval` too.